# Referenced entities show old value when changing properties

Tags: entities, caching

I have three custom entities, all generated with Drupal Console. I only added some basicFieldDefinitions to them before testing some CRUD operations on them.

I have these entities:

- ConfigEntity (config entity - lowest level)
- ChildEntity (content entity - has an entity_reference field to ConfigEntity)
- ParentEntity (content entity - has an entity_reference field to ChildEntity)

When I display the name of the ConfigEntity through the entire chain, it displays properly

```php
// "Original Value"
$parentEntity->get('child_entity')->entity->get('config_entity')->entity->label()
```

When I update the name, it still displays the original value through the chain, although printing it from the entity itself, it is the new value.

```php
// "Original Value"
$parentEntity->get('child_entity')->entity->get('config_entity')->entity->label();

$configEntity = ConfigEntity::load(1);
$configEntity->set('label', "New Value")->save();

$configEntity = ConfigEntity::load(1);

// "New Value"
$configEntity->label();

$parentEntity = ParentEntity::load(1);

// "Original Value" instead of "New Value"
$parentEntity->get('child_entity')->entity->get('config_entity')->entity->label();
```

Any idea if there's a cache tag mechanism I have to implement manually, or something I have to invalidate myself in code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can clear the static entity cache with [EntityStorageBase::resetCache](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21EntityStorageBase.php/function/EntityStorageBase%3A%3AresetCache/8.7.x):

```
\Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('parent_entity')->resetCache([$parentEntity->id()]);
```

Comment: Thanks! 

Is it best to add this to the save() method of the child?

Comment: Most times this is not necessary, because what you are doing is testing and rarely happens in production where you usually save entities in post requests.