# Getting latest entity data from the database

Tags: entities

The problem: I open a `drush php:cli` shell and run the following:

```
>>> \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('paragraph')->load(477)->get('field_end_time')->getValue()[0]['value'];
=> "05:01"
```

I then change the value in the database to `05:02` via the admin panel (content section).

But if I run the same command again in the shell, I still get `05:01`.

If I close the shell and open a new one I get `05:02`. How do I demand the latest data without terminating the process and starting over? This seems like it must be a basic thing but I've searched far and wide and tried clearing caches and etc. but no dice.

This is affecting me because I have a PHP process that is started by cron that handles a Websocket connections and the same thing is happening there—it's getting stale data from the database.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers!  Probably cache related. I guess when you `drupal_flush_all_caches();` in between you will get the right value, but that's probably not what you want? What exactly are you updating that value for? Why a Paragraph when it looks more like config? Can you maybe add some more context? Many thanks 

Comment: Wow you're right! But that method takes like 5 seconds!

This is some legacy code I'm dealing with here. Paragraphs hold some data about a discussion including its closing time.

Comment: What happens when you use the CLI to also set the value instead of doing that directly in the database?

Comment: Is there a way to tell which cache is causing this behavior and clear only that one?

Comment: I'm not sure how to set the value from the CLI honestly but that is not how it would be happening.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can clear the cached entity in memory to get the latest field values:

```
\Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('paragraph')->resetCache([477]);
```

See [Referenced entities show old value when changing properties](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/278925/referenced-entities-show-old-value-when-changing-properties/278926#278926)

Comment: Glorious. Thank you!

Comment: @smoyth – Avoid thank you comments. Accept the answer instead. 